# How do I run the Gitlab project through the Airflow

Tags: docker, gitlab, airflow

I have a GitLab CICD project which pushes the docker image to a private repository. I would like to run this image from the Airflow every day.

I am trying to run this Gitlab project which is hosted on a different sever with Airflow (also on a different server) but I am not sure how would I do it?

My main goal is to run this project every day with Airflow. I would love to hear different ways to do it.